# Official language of Asian Games?

Tags: asian-games

Is there an official language of the Asian Games?

I know that Engish is commonly used, but am not sure whether it is official or unofficial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is English.

In the Constitution of the Olympic Council of Asia (OCA), it is designated as English.

https://ocasia.org/media/oca_files/OCA_CONSTITUTION_AND_RULES__19052022_new_gTkELZw_UF20vN2_yDjwveH.pdf

Please see Chapter 2, Article 42 of the above document.

Comment: But another language might be used in the special occasion by the decision of the General Assembly.